# How to broadcast a function over a numpy array, when dtype=object?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, broadcast

If I have an array of numerical values, which had to use object pointers instead of values as the data type, due to unequal vector lengths:

```
In [145]: import numpy as np

In [147]: a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4,5]])

In [148]: a
Out[148]: array([[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]], dtype=object)

In [150]: np.sin(a)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-150-58d97006f018> in <module>()
----> 1 np.sin(a)

In [152]: np.sin(a[0])
Out[152]: array([ 0.84147098,  0.90929743])
```

How do I broadcast a function over the actual numerical values without having to manually traverse the array?

Comment: There is almost *never* a good reason to use `dtype=object`! The point of using a numpy array over, say, a Python `list` is that it allows you to accelerate operations that require looping over the elements of the array by vectorization - effectively by doing the loops in a lower level language to avoid the overhead inherent in Python. However, by using the `object` type you lose these performance benefits. The elements in your array are just treated as 'dumb' Python objects (in this case, your array just contains two normal `list`s, i.e. with a `shape=(2,)`).

Comment: If I knew more about what the array represents, and why the row lengths are uneven, I could probably suggest a much better solution. As it stands, if you really, really need a ragged array then you might as well use nested `list`s, which will be much cheaper to construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of different issues here. First, there's little to be gained by broadcasting over python objects in numpy; you'll probably do better using pure python in this case.

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], dtype=object)
>>> b = np.arange(1, 7).reshape(2, 3)
>>> c = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> %timeit a * 5
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.28 µs per loop
>>> %timeit b * 5
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.08 µs per loop
>>> %timeit [[x * 5 for x in l] for l in c]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 998 ns per loop
```

Those speeds will scale a bit unevenly but you get the idea.

Second, the problem isn't directly related to broadcasting. `numpy` will happily broadcast over python lists. The result just isn't what you expect:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]], dtype=object)
>>> a * 5
    array([[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5]], dtype=object)
```

`numpy` allows the objects in the array to define their own versions of whichever operator or function it's broadcasting. In this case, python lists define `*` as repetition! This holds even for heterogenous arrays; try this: `np.array([5, [1, 2]], dtype=object) * 5`. The reason `sin` doesn't broadcast in this case is that python lists don't define `sin` at all.

You'd probably be better off using a fixed-width array with a mask.

```
>>> np.ma.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], mask=[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
    masked_array(data =
 [[1 2 3]
 [4 5 --]],
             mask =
 [[False False False]
 [False False  True]],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

As you can see, you can "simulate" a ragged array this way, and it will behave just as expected.

```
>>> a = np.ma.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], mask=[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
>>> np.sin(a)
    masked_array(data =
 [[0.841470984808 0.909297426826 0.14112000806]
 [-0.756802495308 -0.958924274663 --]],
             mask =
 [[False False False]
 [False False  True]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

It's worth mentioning a few ways to create masked arrays. In your case, `masked_invalid` might be useful.

```
>>> np.ma.masked_invalid([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, np.NaN]])
masked_array(data =
 [[1.0 2.0 3.0]
 [4.0 5.0 --]],
             mask =
 [[False False False]
 [False False  True]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

You can also create masked arrays using conditions:

```
>>> x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
>>> np.ma.masked_where(x > 5, x)
masked_array(data =
 [[1 2 3]
 [4 5 --]],
             mask =
 [[False False False]
 [False False  True]],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

For a full list of variations on these techniques, see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html#constructing-masked-arrays).

Answer (score 1):

Like others have suggested, it's best to avoid arrays `dtype=object`.

Another approach for avoiding that, which surprisingly nobody has mentioned so far, is padding with NaNs, in order to achieve a common shape.

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4,5]])
maxlen = max(len(x) for x in a)
b = np.array([ x+[np.NaN]*(maxlen-len(x)) for x in a ])
b
=> array([[  1.,   2.,  nan], [  3.,   4.,   5.]])
b.shape
=> (2, 3)
np.sin(b) 
=> array([[ 0.84147098,  0.90929743,         nan],
          [ 0.14112001, -0.7568025 , -0.95892427]])
```

Of course, handling arrays containing NaNs should be done with care, e.g. you probably want to use `nanmax` instead of `max`, etc.

Comment: Masked arrays are the preferred way to do this sort of thing. They avoid the awkwardness of having to resort to `nanmax` and friends.