# Sums of arrays in an array

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, sum

Is there a speedy way to do this;

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([1,2,3,4])
b=np.array([1,2])
c=np.array([a,b])
result=magic(c)
```

where `magic()` is the functionality I want and result should be `np.array([10,3])` i.e. a `numpy.array` containing the sums of each of the input arrays.

Comment: Why not `sums = [sum(arr) for arr in [a, b]]`?

Comment: Are `a`, `b`, etc longer or shorter than `c`, typically? Is `c` already created, or can we bypass that step?

Comment: Well I was hoping for a nice numpy implementation avoiding loops. @Oliver. W tells me that operations on unequal length arrays are not efficient in numpy so maybe the answer is to think of a different way to store my data...

Comment: @askewchan  `a` and `b` can vary between length 1 and a few 100. `c` typically has length of a few tens and `c` is already created.

Comment: `np.add.reduceat(d,ind)` is a fast way of summing uneven blocks of the array `d`.  But constructing `d` (`np.hstack(c)`) and `ind` takes time.

Comment: @hpaulj, I took the liberty of implementing and timing your suggestion, alongside other solutions. If you would like to post your own version as an answer, I can take mine down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the many possible solutions, this is one:

```
def your_magic(arr):
    res = np.empty_like(arr)
    for enu, subarr in enumerate(arr):
        res[enu] = np.sum(subarr)
    return res
```

Be mindful though that making a numpy array of unequal length arrays is not efficient at all and is just very similar to adding arrays in a normal Python list. This is the reason the returned array `res` in the function above will in general be of the dtype `object`.

Comment: Thanks! when you say not efficient are we talking memory/speed/both?

Comment: @fen speed: numpy was designed for computing on contiguous blocks of memory. By making it into a forced list of objects, you're adding unnecessary housekeeping under the hood. Have a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23795569/2476444), in particular the first comment and first post. @Reut's comment to your post is an elegant way as well to define your magic function (although a case could be made to use the numpy method `sum` rather than the python builtin).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a compilation of the suggestions (answers and comments) and their timings:

```
import numpy as np

c = np.array([np.random.rand(np.random.randint(1, 300)) for i in range(50)])

def oliver(arr):
    res = np.empty_like(arr)
    for enu, subarr in enumerate(arr):
        res[enu] = np.sum(subarr)
    return res

def reut(arr):
    return np.array([a.sum() for a in arr])

def hpaulj(arr):
    d = np.concatenate(arr)
    l = map(len, arr)
    i = np.cumsum(l) - l
    return np.add.reduceat(d, i)
```

And their times:

```
In [94]: timeit oliver(c)
1000 loops, best of 3: 457 µs per loop

In [95]: timeit reut(c)
1000 loops, best of 3: 317 µs per loop

In [96]: timeit hpaulj(c)
10000 loops, best of 3: 94.4 µs per loop
```

It was somewhat tricky to implement @hpaulj's, but I think I got it (and it's the fastest if you use `concatenate` instead of `hstack`)